# One column wider - Amcharts 4

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

I made one column wider than the others, and now this wider column overlaps the others. Is there any way to make the columns appear one above the other? Unfortunately I can't find anything.
[Amcharts 4 chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0XSU.png)